# Suggestion for badges: Epic question and Epic answer

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Badge: Hard Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78568/new-badge-hard-question)

I saw that question:
[Debug PostgreSQL function using pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865615/debug-postgresql-function-using-pgadmin)

Currently it is upvoted to score 42, has a lot of comments, a lot of views, some stars and not a single answer. I think that this guy deserved a gold medal for that.

Ok, nothing stops someone to get there and post a stupid answer just to say that it was answered. So my suggestion is:

If the question is open for more than 30 days, has 30+ score, has no accepted answer and no 2+ scored answer, then the author of the question gets the gold medal "Epic question". This badge encourage people to do smart and important questions.

And obviously, answering to a question that already got that medal and get the answer accepted gives "Epic answer" medal. Needless to say, this would encourage people to pursue an answer to the hardest unanswered questions, and to help the question author and everyone that upvoted the question.

Further, we could think about the equivalent smaller versions for silver and bronze medals.

Comment: up vote for your good mind to improve stack overflow. I don't think he intentionally duplicated that question so the down vote is not a good manner to a kind man who type all these words and just want to give advise to this site he loves.

Comment: @LotusH: Thanks. I did not saw the other question. There is a lot of badges suggestions here, and it is quite difficult to search them.