# New badge for uninteresting question with interesting answers

Tags: feature-request, specific-question, badge-request

After some search, I'd like to propose a badge completely the opposite of [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78568/new-badge-hard-question).

[edit] "Won't" suggested I'd upload an image, here it is: [image]

I got the base idea after that one of [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587243/is-there-a-standard-int-class-in-c) gained quite a lot of interest, a lot of answers in the first minutes, lots of comments and up votes (for the answers) in the end but the question still at zero (up votes).

Wouldn't a badge like "Simple question", "Professors nightmare" or "Philosopher question" be adequate here?

Comment: +...er...-...er...*::no vote::* just for the irony.

Comment: I don't like the idea of this badge. Thinking back over questions, this scenario happens **a lot** for questions which are too localized. The question itself doesn't attract upvotes because it's a horribly simple question that could easily be solved on Google, but it's tagged with something popular so it gets a few answers and the first one posted gets a flood of upvotes from everyone visiting.

Comment: And how could the system possibly be able to automatically tell the difference between an interesting and uninteresting question?  How would this be judged?

Comment: You can't just get the answer out of Google for that one, but OK I understand that you can't decide which questions are "good" or "bad". I thought it could have been interesting, a bit like the "thumbleweed" tag but OK, the community don't think so :-) (if someone can please delete this post as I can't).

Comment: Don't worry, its meta rep.  If you want to get it back, add an image to your question with a freehand circle in it to illustrate.  You'll get at least two upvotes just for that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try by uploading a "nice" image :-)

Comment: Editing your question to "please forget the question" is discouraged. This is not a forum.

Comment: The freehand circle was pretty limp, but you tried hard with the freehand writing so +1.

Answer (score 17):

What's the reasoning behind rewarding someone for asking an uninteresting question? Shouldn't we try not to reward them so they ask more interesting questions?

And we do have a badge in this sort of area: [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) is awarded to the question *answerer* for providing an answer with score >= +20 on a question with score <= -5.

*EDIT:* I'm anticipating the delicious irony of getting the Reversal badge on this answer. On a related note, here's a picture of some particularly delicious-looking waffles:

[image: Waffles.]

Comment: [And its damn hard to get!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122980/172936) ;)

Comment: @Lix I +1'd. You made some good points! Hope you get it :D

Comment: @Lix - You're welcome.  :-)

Comment: Yay! Thanks guys :P  *first gold* on meta ^_^

Comment: You're almost there :-/

Comment: @Valmond: I doubt I'll get many more upvotes here. Maybe in a couple weeks I might.

Comment: I would have upvoted for the picture of waffles, but they've got caramel sauce. I don't do caramel. Can you do more ice cream and more berry couli instead? You should do it, it might be me who takes you from 19 votes up to the magical 20.

Comment: Hey I'm almost there (here) :-D !